# Converting binary number to string python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to iterate over the input `011` as a string like:

```
val = str(011)
for _iter in range(len(val)):
    if _iter[i]=='1':
        print "yes"
```

But on checking the values, it seems to give different ouput.

```
>>> val = str(011)
>>> val
'9'
>>> val = str(42565)
>>> val
'42565'
```

Why I am getting `'9'` for the above value ??

**Implementation**:

I want to display the values of a list 

suppose `list = [1,2,3]` according to the string `011` 
so the output will be

```
2
3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the output you're trying to get?

Comment: Isn't the `0` prefix for octal? Also, use `0b` for binary and `0o` for octal and forward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
011
```

Having a '0' prefix, is interpreted as an *octal* (base 8) number. 1*8 + 1 = 9

If you want to iterate over the characters, then simply make it a string by enclosing it in quotes:

```
val = '011'
```

To convert a string of 0 and 1 characters like this to an *integer*, you can call `int` like this:

```
int(val, base=2)
```

To bypass the string parsing, and simply assign a binary constant to a variable, use the `0b` prefix:

```
val = 0b011
print val     # outputs 3
```